# toroidal surface

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

The normal of any point on a toroidal surface passes through the rotation axis of this surface. Now there are 3 points (close together) on the surface, which make a (small, planar) triangle. I am looking for a point on this triangle from where the normal of the triangle also passes through the axis of the toroidal surface. I tried with the center of the circumscribed circle of the triangle, but this is not the correct point. the question is: is there a general rule to find the footpoint for the normal on the triangle, without using the surface.[image]

Comment: I am not sure that is always possible, but you could try to find a point on the surface which happens to have the same normal as the triangle and then see if the normal of that point passes though the triangle. I know that you don't want to use the surface, but I think you need to use it somehow (perhaps implicitly) anyway. Let me put it this way: for one particular triangle there are several different toroidal surfaces which have their axes in different places (that is, you at least need both radii).

Comment: "for one particular triangle there are several different toroidal surfaces which have their axes in different places": So in my situation where I have several such triangles and want to find the toroidal surface this seems to be the wrong approach.

Comment: If you have a number of triangles, then their coordinates probably are enough, as you can use them to calculate the radii, even if you don't have them.

Comment: That is not true for a cylinder, I would be surprised if it should hold for a torus.